# How to get only FILES in python?

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu, operating-system

I just need to get the files in the directory. I use the os module for this. But I can't view only files in the directory.

`os.chdir("/my/directory1")
files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for f_name in files:
     print(f_name)`

What should I do for this?

Comment: What else do you see, other than the files?

Comment: i see other directories inside directory1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using os.path:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```